# Multi Store views data

Tags: extensions, magento2.3, multistore, store-view

In my site having multi stores. I want to made extension for Multi Store views in the store view option in custom module in adminhtml. How to add functionality for that? i want save the data for different store.

update:

```
<?php

namespace Helpdesk\Block\Adminhtml\Status\Edit;


class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,
        \Helpdesk\Model\Recordstatus $options,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_options = $options;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareForm()
    {
        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'edit_form',
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                            'method' => 'post'
                        ]
            ]
        );

        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('uni_');


                $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('General Information')]);



        $fieldset->addField('store', 'hidden', ['name' => 'store']);

        $data['store'] = 0;
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')){
            $data['store'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
        }

               if (!$this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $field = $fieldset->addField(
                'store_id',
                'multiselect',
                [
                    'name' => 'stores[]',
                    'label' => __('Store View'),
                    'title' => __('Store View'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'values' => $this->_systemStore->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true)
                ]
            );
            $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element'
            );
            $field->setRenderer($renderer);
        } else {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'store_id',
                'hidden',
                ['name' => 'stores[]', 'value' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId()]
            );
            $model->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore(true)->getId());
        }


        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Edit Row Data'), 'class' => 'field-row-data']
            );
            $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'entity_id']);
        } else {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
                'base_fieldset',
                ['legend' => __('Add Row Data'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
            );
        }

        $fieldset->addField(
            'title',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'title',
                'label' => __('Title'),
                'id' => 'title',
                'title' => __('Title'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'status',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'status',
                'label' => __('Status'),
                'id' => 'status',
                'title' => __('Status'),
                'values' => $this->_options->getOptionArray(),
                'class' => 'status',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

and added this in xml to tried too,but not save.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Backend::store/switcher.phtml">
        <action method="setUseConfirm">
            <argument name="params" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: which platform are you using ?

Comment: magento2.3 , i tried in developer to translate but not work @AnasMansuri

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html - check with this url, i hope its very helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, but not in System.xml, is in a extension, look like Catalog > Categories > Store View: All Store Views <--how can i add this function? @AnasMansuri

Comment: Now please check with this - https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Add-store-id-to-custom-module-table-Magento-2-2-2/td-p/94437

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will check it, but i getting error in this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277777/uncaught-error-call-to-a-member-function-getid-on-null-in?noredirect=1#comment396450_277777 , do you know how to fix it? thank you! @AnasMansuri

Comment: i have tried is work but the translate data not save in the different language store, how can i made it , thank you @AnasMansuri

Comment: you will need to post some code examples in order for this to be debugged properly

Comment: i maked this file, please check the update, but not work for save too. @bjornredemption

Comment: the code is work but not save for different language store, all save will be same now. @bjornredemption

Comment: please check original post,thank you! @bjornredemption