# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in

Tags: helper

I have some problem about this error, who can tell me why? Thank you!!
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in

Comment: Please detail $customer = $this->helperData->getCustomer();

Comment: sorry,what your mean? @HoangHieu

Comment: $this->helperData->getCustomer(); this function returned null, please detail it.

Comment: This have no return, just return $collection. and when i changed other code it can work for no login, but login will be error. @HoangHieu

Comment: did you `print_r($customer)` to check is it returning something or not?

Comment: not  to returning @AsadKhan

Comment: if i added this code it will work but just for no login `if (empty($customer->getData())) {
            $this->_redirect($this->helperData->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        }` @HoangHieu

Comment: if i added this code it will work but just for no login `if (empty($customer->getData())) {
            $this->_redirect($this->helperData->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
        }` @AsadKhan

Comment: @niceonelee can you paste function code of getCustomer() class Helpdesk\Helper\Data  ?

Comment: please check the original post, this is full file code, thank you! @AnsarHusain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is more logic than syntax, if the customer isn't logged in (guest) you cannot get the user id. I would edit your helper function to check if the user is logged in and return false if not.

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    $customerSession = $this->customerSession->create();
    $customerData = $customerSession->getCustomerData();
    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
        return $customerData;
     } else{
         return false;
     }
}
```

Then in your getTicket function use something like this :

```
if ($this->helperData->getCustomer()){
  // run your code as normal
} else {
  // redirect to login
}
```

Comment: you should mark this as the answer in that case

Comment: yes,marked,can you help me see the second issue,thank you @bjornredemption

Answer (score 0):

```
 $user_id = $customer->getId();
```

this code return int or null,when return null,the program will automatically throw an error.You should handle your mistakes properly.eg:

```
if ($user_id) {
//your code
}else{
 //your code
}
```

Comment: im still getting error, can you made a full code let me to see what i wrong, thank you!! @tokey

Comment: getting this `1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: user_id`

Comment: @niceonelee Please show your complete code.

Comment: please check the original post, this is full file code, thank you! @tokey

Comment: @niceonelee But you didn't modify your code as I suggested.

Comment: please check again ,thank you! `Undefined variable: user_id` @tokey